# Unable to generate auto generated files in relay compiler for mutations

Tags: reactjs, relay, relaycommand

I am trying to create a web application with `ReactJs` as frontend, `GraphQL` as service layer and `Relay` as communication between service layer and frontend.

In this i created a mutation in service layer and integrated in front end.At last tried to generate files using following commands

1. relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql
2. get-graphql-schema http://localhost:6001/xampr > schema.graphql

None of these are working by throwing this errors

- Writing js

  > ERROR:
  >   You supplied a GraphQL document with validation errors:Unknown type "GetActivityMessagesRequestInput".
  >   Services/Auth/GetActivityMessagesMutation.js (2:49)
  >   1: 2:     mutation GetActivityMessagesMutation($input:GetActivityMessagesRequestInput!) {
  >                                                  ^3:         getActivityMessagesRequest(input : $input){
  >   error Command failed with exit code 100.
- GraphQL is not found
- Stack is empty unable to convert undefined to graphQL query

My relay script tag is

```
"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql --watchman false"
```

Tried to uninstall an reinstall all packages

```
"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql --watchman false"
```

Unable to create generated mutation files using relay compiler

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, `GetActivityMessagesRequestInput` isn't a valid graphQL `input` defined in your schema.

Check your server schema for that `input` definition if it exists, else see what the right `input` to pass to that mutation is. You might as well call the `scalar input` directly.

It might be `GetActivityMessagesCreateInput`.

Example to demonstrate what I mean.

`signin(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload!
 updateProfile(data: UserUpdateInput!, id: ID): User!`

If I call sign mutation like so

`mutation SignIn ($input: SignInMutationInput!) {
   signin(input: $input){
     user: { id, email }
     token
}`

It will return the same error as yours saying `You supplied a GraphQL document with validation errors:Unknown type "SignInMutationInput"`

To fix the above, I can either create a custom input type in my server called `input SignInMutationInput { email: String! password: String! }` OR
change the way I'm calling the mutation like so;

`mutation SignIn ($email: String!, $password: String! ) {
   signin(email: $email, password: $password){
     user: { id, email }
     token
}`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tq for suggestion.Yes,there is issue with input file format.

Comment: Awesome, you can make this as the accepted answer with an upvote also to enable visibility for others with similar issues. 